# I want to plug ADT plugins with eclipse 3.5 using ADT-0.9.3.zip archive

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, installation, adt

I am facing a problem of installing ADT from

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

and

```
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

It shows some transfer error.

I have downloaded the ADT plugin archive ADT-0.9.3.zip

Can i use this archive? 
If yes please let me know.
If no, then please tell me some alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADT-0.9.3.zip is an **archived site**.

That means, through the [p2 provisioning interface](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Update_UI_Users_Guide), you need to add a new site which will actually be that .zip file. (Note: works best with eclipse3.5 instead of 3.4.)

[image]

Click on "Add Site"

[image]

From there, you will be able to install it.